# Resource Bundle - anyone who care to explain?

Tags: java, localization, resourcebundle

Yet again I am asking something for my project and I pretty much feel like I am a total newb in Java...
  Anyway, I was recently told about ResourceBundle. My real problem is that I cannot understand the Oracle Documentation on the class in general and that I get some weird compile-time errors.
  First off I made three Bundles mwb `extends java.util.ResourceBundle`, a second `mwb_el extends mwb` and a third `mwb_en extends mwb`. I made a `contents` variable of type `Object[][]` and wrote a method `getContents()` that `return cotents;`! Then I went into each class and changed the values for the second field in each line (not the key, the value). No I am stuck at a point that I cannot really get how to handle getting the values.
  I checked some tutorials and examples but I got even more confused. What I need is someone to explain to me:

1. How do I make the mwb object I create and initialize in a class get the locale I want
   it to.
2. How do I get a certain value. I tried getObject(), getString() even
   the getContents() and even overriden the handleGetObject() to
       no avail.

   Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Why are you extending the `ResourceBundle`? If possible show us what you are doing. Also check this tutorial - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/intro/after.html.

Comment: How shall I make my resourcebundle then? I see that I make a file that is .properties. Is it just a text file with this extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Property file should have messages in key/value pairs.

e.g

```
key1=message1
key2=message2
```

If you have a resource file called "MessagesBundle_en_US.properties" you can load it as follows.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");
ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessagesBundle", locale);
```

then `messages.getString("key1")` should return "message1".